# How to change the text of a NativeScript label

Tags: user-interface, label, nativescript

I am new to NativeScript and I need to be able to change the text of a label. I am confused about how to do this and need help. How can I do this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**First way:**

You can set an `id` for the label that you want to get, and reference it in controller file(which is `.js`) by using `getViewById`:

In page.xml:

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" loaded="onLoaded">
    <Label id="myLabel" text="" />
</Page>
```

In page.js:

```
function onLoaded(args) {
    var page = args.object;
    var myLabel = page.getViewById("myLabel");
    myLabel.text = "Hello World";
}
exports.onLoaded = onLoaded
```

**Second way:**

You bind a context(an Observable object) to page.xml and set the text of label by one of that context's properties. By this way when you change the value of property, the label will update the text by itself:

In page.xml:

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" loaded="onLoaded">
    <Label text="{{ myText }}" />
</Page>
```

In page.js:

```
var Observable = require("data/observable").Observable;
function onLoaded(args) {
    var page = args.object;
    var context = new Observable({
        myText: "Hello World"
    })
    page.bindingContext = context;
    //Change label's text
    context.set("myText", "Goodbye World");
}
exports.onLoaded = onLoaded;
```